# Can't locate perl module in @INC after install the module

Tags: perl

I am really new to perl and trying to use the [BioPerl](https://bioperl.org/INSTALL.html) module on CentOS 7 with apache2. After I successfully installed the module, the program still complain that it can't locate Bio/SeqIO.pm in @INC.

Full error trace:

```
Cant locate Bio/SeqIO.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .. ../ /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at superpose/seqAlign.pm line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at superpose/seqAlign.pm line 39.
Compilation failed in require at superpose/superposeController.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at superpose/superposeController.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/superpose.cgi line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/superpose.cgi line 11.
```

Here is the location that I found the bioperl module:

```
/root/.cpan/build/BioPerl-1.007002-oajj3K/Bio
/root/.cpan/build/BioPerl-1.007002-oajj3K/blib/lib/Bio
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Bio
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551466691.17906/BioPerl-1.007002/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551466691.17906/BioPerl-1.007002/blib/lib/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551734157.15167/BioPerl-1.007002/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551734157.15167/BioPerl-1.007002/blib/lib/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551825394.27587/BioPerl-1.007002/Bio
/root/.cpanm/work/1551825394.27587/BioPerl-1.007002/blib/lib/Bio
```

The @INC and %ENV from 
    perl -V

```
%ENV:
PERL5LIB="/root/perl5/lib/perl5:"
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=":/root/perl5"
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /root/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5"
@INC:
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
```

I realized that my @INC doesn't contain the path to "/root/perl5/lib/perl5/Bio", but I think as long as PERL5LIB contain "/root/perl5/lib/perl5", it should be able to find the module.

For the seqAlign.pm script, it links the perl library like this:

```
....
use lib qw(..);
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

use Bio::SeqIO;
use Bio::PrimarySeq;
....
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you running the program as root? Do you have permissions to read the module? How did you install the module?

Comment: Where is Bio/SeqIO.pm?

Comment: You showed the `@INC` and `%ENV` from a different environment than the one in which you ran your script.

Comment: Tip: `use lib qw(..);` looks in the parent directory of the current work directory, not the parent directory for the script's directory. For that, you want `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/..";`. This won't fix the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've demonstrated that setting `PERL5LIB` to `/root/perl5/lib/perl5` causes the following to be prepended to `@INC`:

```
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5
```

However, these are absent in the `@INC` of the `perl` that gave the error message, so `PERL5LIB` is clearly not set to `/root/perl5/lib/perl5` in environment in which you ran your script. Setting it appropriately in that environment will fix your problem.